# Text To Speech(TTS) plugin for Phonegap iOS

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, phonegap-plugins

I am developing a application in Phonegap iOS by using Xcode.I need Text To Speech(TTS) plugin for Phonegap iOS. I am facing problem with this. Can anyone help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Text To Speech(TTS)**

https://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts/src
https://github.com/todoroo/iPhone-Speech-To-Text
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/TTS
https://github.com/macdonst/TTS
http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/10/12/First-test-of-PhoneGap-Plugins
http://en.usenet.digipedia.org/thread/12992/27474/ 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/phonegap/JSBV8zfbXZ0/JqiLM5HdTF4J
http://phonegap.com/blog/2012/09/

This linke may be helpful for you :)

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I cannot find the Text To Speech(TTS) plugin in those links.

Comment: Ok I saw these links before you posted here but I cannot figured TTS because first two links apps are not working properly. Android TTS plugin is working but iOS plugin is not working.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I need Text To Speech(TTS) plugin for iOS.

Comment: None of the links you dumped into your answer actually address the question asked.  @Chakradhar asked for a PhoneGap plugin for Text To Speech on iOS (a subject that he's not alone in looking for) and you gave him links to TTS in XCode, TTS for Android, and one on Speech to Text for iOS.

Comment: For iOS you can do it without a plugin 

var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello World');
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

But the quality is not ideal.  You will have to slow the voice down and make it more beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

This is one is supposed to work on ios (and Android) https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1730

Although i haven't been able to get it to work (using PhoneGap Build)